# Dynamically populated jQuery Mobile Listview items with jQuery.tmpl do not get jQuery mobile styles

Tags: jquery-mobile, jquery-templates

I have created a jsfiddle of my problem. [Here is a link to the jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/bdetchison/ZgsCM/) I assume this will be easy for someone that has has used jquery mobile a good amount.

I am using jquery mobile in combination with jquery.tmpl.  Basically as you can see from the example the I am taking my JSON object and passing it to the .appendTo call.  It appears to be correctly using the template to create the `<li>`'s

The problem is the the dynamically created `<li>`'s do not get the JQM styles like the one I had in there in the mark up.

I have spent a couple hours looking at this and most people say that `$("dynamicContentHolder").listview("refresh");` or `$("dynamicContentHolder").listview();` or both together will fix the problem. According to JQM documentation [(LINK)](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html) I should be binding on the pageinit event so this is called every time the page is loaded directly or ajax nav. According to JQM as well [(LINK)](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/lists/docs-lists.html) I should be using `.listview('refresh')` to updating the styling of the newly added `<li>`'s.

It seems like the code should be working, not sure what I am missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a duh moment,  I found the error 2 minutes after I submitted.  My jQuery selector was incorrect `$("#dynamicContentHolder").listview("refresh");`